# django.db.utils.IntegrityError and sqlite3.IntegrityError

Tags: django, sqlite, django-templates

I'm following a Django tutorial to train and make a simple poll site. At a certain point, when I need to get the server running and add questions to the polls, I come across the error codes below:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_question.question_text
```

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_question.question_text
```

I expected to be able to add questions in the questions field created in the database, but I came across this mistakes. What do I do?

Comment: You must be sending `question_text` as None that's why you are getting this error. `question_text` is not a null field.

Comment: I m trying localize the file for insert one value, but i cant localize him.

Comment: did not get you, sorry.

Comment: Desculpe pela falta de clareza. Meu inglês não é tão bom e o Google Tradutor não ajuda muito. O que eu quis dizer é que eu estava tentando localizar este arquivo chamado "question_text" para mudar o seu valor. Na realidade nem sei se é realmente isso que eu devo fazer. A questão é que o erro que aparece agora é este: TypeError: Question() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'question_text', 'pub_date'. Vale lembrar que estou seguindo este tutorial do Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/4.2/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: Can you show your code and payload? So that I can help you.

Comment: Acho que não entendi o que quis dizer com payload. Ainda sou iniciante. Porém, este é o código presente no arquivo **polls.models.py**:

```import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text```

Comment: I'm coming back here just to say that, for a mystery, the problem was solved and I was able to insert questions in the polls. Thank you for your willingness to respond.